# Post title as link parameter

Tags: parameter

I have in the theme file single.php a link in it (example.com/cars/?aff=) in each post of my blog is displayed. That's how I integrated it:

```
$html .="<a id='test' rel='nofollow' href='https://example.com/cars/?aff=' target='_blank'>";
```

I would like the title of the post to be automatically written behind **?aff=**

For example: `https://example.com/cars/?aff=POSTTITLE`

How do I accomplish this? Have googled allot but cannot find anything.

Would be glad about help!

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to accomplish?

```
$html .="<a id='test' rel='nofollow' href='https://example.com/cars/?aff='". echo get_the_title( $post_id ) ." target='_blank'>";
```